# Value of Toast to TextView of second activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toast

This is my MainActivity.java and I want the results in a text view of another activity? How can I achieve it? Can you Show me with an example please.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button scan_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scan_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnQr);
    final Activity activity =this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            intentIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            intentIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null){
        if (result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this,"You cancelled scanning",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
    else {


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
}
```

This is my Second Activity. Where I want to show the result.

```
  public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private TextView qrResult;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

qrResult= findViewById(R.id.qrResult);



}
}
```

If you want I can post my Layout file as well. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put data into the intent from your main acivity and the get the intend from the second activity for the data.
For example:

**In your `MainActivity.class`**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("result", "Your result text here");
        startActivity(intent);
```

**In Your `DetailsActivity.class`**:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String result = intent.getStringExtra("result");
qrResult.setText(result);
```

**You can even send any type of object through intent. Please google it for further information.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new Intent object, and add it extra data with intent.putextra(). This method can take a String object as an argument. You need to specify a unique key for that string.Then start the new activity. For example
Intent i = new Intent(context, nextactivity.class)
i.putextra(“stringKey”,yourSstring)
startActivity(i)

Then, in the second activity, you need to get the intent that started that activity (with getIntent), you can use it as early as onCreate.
The getIntent function returns the intent object that started the new activity.
When you have the new intent, you can get the extra string you passed from the old activity, with intent.getStringExtra(“stringKey”)
This allows you to pass simple data between activities. Make sure to use the same key.